# How to include DirectX libraries into my own static library (stand-alone lib)?

Tags: c++, directx, static-libraries

I am writting my own library that implements the Engine3D interface (made by me).

The 'user' of that library should include it (and the header for the Engine3D interface) in its project and run it without any additional libraries etc.

Unfortunatelly, when I make a static library from my project, the 'user' have to include both my library and DirectX libs, set the directories for DirectX etc.

**Is there any way to make it simple** (just one lib is everything he needs) **and transparent for the user** (**no DirectX libs, directories in the project, all *inside* my own library**)?

I'm using Visual C++ 2012. I don't want to make a dynamic library, but the static one.

Answer (score 2):

Huge coincidence, cause I've had the exact same problem an hour ago, and found a very simple solution. If you are using the #pragma comment directives to include your Directx libs, you just have to provide them the full path of your libs (instead of only the name) like this :

```
#pragma comment ( lib, "c:/Softwares/Development/Lib/DirectX/Lib/x86/dxgi.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "c:/Softwares/Development/Lib/DirectX/Lib/x86/d3d11.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "c:/Softwares/Development/Lib/DirectX/Lib/x86/d3dx11.lib" )
#pragma comment ( lib, "c:/Softwares/Development/Lib/DirectX/Lib/x86/d3dx10.lib" )
```

Obviously, the path in my example is related to my personal configuration, and you should define the correct path to your DirectX libs directory on your computer. Then, you just have to go to your project configuration -> C/C++ -> General -> Additionnal Include Directories and set the path to your DirectX includes files.

That's it! Now you can compile your DirectX interface and link it to another project without the need to make more setup thereafter.

I hope it will help you, and sorry about my bad English. : )